# addEventListener not working when used within addClass

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, material-design

I have written the following HTML, using Material Design Lite for a progress bar:

```
<div class="mdl-grid">
    <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--12-col mdl-cell--12-col-phone">
        <div id="stepProgress" class="mdl-progress mdl-js-progress"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="mdl-grid">
    <div id="step1-title" class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--4-col mdl-cell--4-col-phone steps">
        <h5 class="text-center">Step 1</h5>
    </div>
    <div id="step2-title" class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--4-col mdl-cell--4-col-phone steps">
         <h5 class="text-center">Step 2</h5>
    </div>
    <div id="step3-title" class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--4-col mdl-cell--4-col-phone steps">
         <h5 class="text-center">Step 3</h5>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="firstnext" class="box-style">Next</div>
```

Tha layout looks great. When a button is pressed it changes the background on each of the steps to indicate which step the user is in, using the following jQuery:

```
jQuery('#step1-title').addClass('box-active');
jQuery('#firstnext,#step2-title').click(function(){

    jQuery('#step1').hide();
    jQuery('#step2').show();
    jQuery('#step3').hide();
    jQuery('#step1-title').removeClass('box-active');
    jQuery('#step2-title').addClass('box-active');
    jQuery('#step3-title').removeClass('box-active');

});
```

I am now trying to update the progress bar but the following isn't working when the next button is pressed:

```
document.querySelector('#stepProgress').addEventListener('mdl-componentupgraded', function() {
this.MaterialProgress.setProgress(33);
});
```

(from Google's site here: https://getmdl.io/components/#loading-section)

I've created the following jsFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/storm/7a84vqz7/

Comment: can you please create the fiddle of it ?

Comment: Could you build a JSFiddle?

Comment: I just created the fiddle for you here: https://jsfiddle.net/vf2c71t2/ It's working find check it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example code on the provided link, reacts to the `mdl-componentupgraded` event, assuming that some background process updates the component. Although I don't know the underlying workings, it seems you can set set the progress directly via:

```
document.querySelector('#stepProgress').MaterialProgress.setProgress(33);
```

Comment: Working great! Thank you